# Codeigniter PostgreSQL Run Via CLI Not Working

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, command-line-interface

I have codeigniter project with postgre database connection. It works fine in the browser but not in the CLI.

Here is my Codeigniter database connection:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'my_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

When i'm running Codeigniter in the CLI, it said:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type:        Error
Message:     Call to undefined function pg_connect()
Filename:    F:\xampp\htdocs\crawls\system\database\drivers\postgre\postgre_driver.php
Line Number: 154

Backtrace:
        File: F:\xampp\htdocs\crawls\application\controllers\Playground.php
        Line: 9
        Function: __construct

        File: F:\xampp\htdocs\crawls\index.php
        Line: 315
        Function: require_once
```

Here is my command to run it via CLI:

```
php index.php playground test
```

What should i fix? So i can run the Codeigniter with Postgre DB through the CLI

Im running it on PHP 5.6.12 using XAMPP and in Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Go to your XAMPP installed folder and go to PHP folder.

Find php.ini file.

Remove Comment `;` from line `;extension=php_pgsql.dll`

Restart the server.

Run `php --ini` command and check it shows correct php.ini path or not.

If not, use following configuration to run php file

```
php -c D:/xamp-path/php/php.ini -f index.php playground test
```

Comment: It's already removed. Like i said in my question, it's actually work well in the browser, but not working in the CLI

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea any solution ? same problem here =(